# How to write or import Bootstrap in React-Native

Tags: react-native, bootstrap-4

I want to know how to import bootstrap in React-Native if not what are the alternatives for using Bootstrap's Grid System in React-Native.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `flex` system which is built-in.

Take a look at [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)!

Answer (score 0):

You can't because app is not the same ad webdev.

If you are looking for a UI kit I can suggest you https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/